# C readdir & struct dirent allocation

Tags: c, readdir, dirent.h

`readdir` return a pointer to a `struct dirent`, I have tested if two calls to `readdir` stored in two different pointers modify the first pointer content, it doesn't.

So I guess readdir allocate some memory, am I right ?

If so, it should be released, something I never did before...

Comment: What does the man page say?

Comment: `The  data  returned by readdir() may be overwritten by subsequent calls
       to readdir() for the same directory stream.`, like I said in the post, after two calls it hasn't change the first struct.
Is it because it has a buffer of entries, and after a certain number of calls it load the rest of the next part in the buffer ?

Comment: It says *"may be"*. It also says *"do not free it."* I presume you called `opendir` first, and then after use `closedir` as per the answers?

Answer (score 2):

POSIX says that an application must not modify the structure returned by [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html):

> The application shall not modify the structure to which the return
>   value of readdir() points, nor any storage areas pointed to by
>   pointers within the structure. The returned pointer, and pointers
>   within the structure, might be invalidated or the structure or the
>   storage areas might be overwritten by a subsequent call to readdir()
>   on the same directory stream. They shall not be affected by a call to
>   readdir() on a different directory stream.

So whether it internally allocates memory or uses a static buffer depends on how how a specific implementation implements. All you need to do is respect the contract that the function requires. That is, you must not attempt to modify it and call `closedir()` to close the directory stream.

Comment: For a project I need to implement those functions in a "Tiny Toy Filesystem", that's why I need details about the implementation !

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto POSIX doesn't require `readdir()` to be re-entrant or thread-safe. So a trivial implementation could use `static` buffer and can still be compliant.

Comment: The last line of the POSIX quote says that you need at least one unique buffer for each call to `opendir`, so it can't be a system-wide `static` buffer. It could be a `struct dirent` that's embedded in the `DIR` structure (where the DIR structure is dynamically allocated by `opendir` and freed by `closedir`).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry it's more complicated in my case since I also had to implements the disk io api and make all these work together in a good way is somewhat complicated !
What I thought could be problmatic was the use of a buffer when concurrency enter in the game... If the disk is modified, the buffer doesn't have the right content.

Answer (score 1):

If it does allocated any memory the call to closedir (http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) will free it up for you

Comment: This would mean that calls to `readdir` fill a `struct dirent *` dynamic array, it's strange... It could be huge... I would love to know how streams works ! Does it load all content in a buffer ? Like I just said previously it could be huge...

Comment: You only need one for the directory stream. See the quote in the other post

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it should be released. You should call `closedir` on a directory after `readdir`, just like you call `fclose` after `fopen` for regular files.